# A value of type 'Null' can't be returned by the 'onError' handler

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I can't return a null from catchError handler of dart Future. I can do it using try catch but I need to use then catchError.

Using try catch

```
 Future<bool?> test() async {
    try {
      return await someFuture();
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

// Works without error
```

But when using then catchError

```
  Future<bool?> test() {
    return someFuture().catchError((e) {
      return null;
    });
  }

// Error: A value of type 'Null' can't be returned by the 'onError' handler because it must be assignable to 'FutureOr<bool>'
```

How do I return null if I encounter some error using then and catchError?

Comment: The type of `someFuture` needs to be able to return `null` since `catchError` just gets the same return type as `someFuture`.

Comment: Making someFuture able to return null gives same error in runtime whereas previously it gave warning on compile time.

Answer (score 3):

This example works where I have made `someFuture` to return `bool?`:

```
Future<bool?> someFuture() async {
  throw Exception('Error');
}

Future<bool?> test() {
  return someFuture().catchError((Object e) => null);
}

Future<void> main() async {
  print('Our value: ${await test()}'); // Our value: null
}
```

If you can't change the return type of the `someFuture` method we can also do this where we creates a new future based on another future but where we specify that our type is nullable:

```
Future<bool> someFuture() async {
  throw Exception('Error');
}

Future<bool?> test() {
  return Future<bool?>(someFuture).catchError((Object e) => null);
}

Future<void> main() async {
  print('Our value: ${await test()}'); // Our value: null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should specify someFuture() signature, which probably returns `Future<bool>`

```
Future<bool> someFuture() async
```

Method `catchError` must return the same future type it is called on. You can overcome this by forwarding the value to `then` and convert it to `Future<bool?>`:

```
Future<bool?> test() {
    return someFuture()
 .then((value) => Future<bool?>.value(value))
 .catchError((e) {
    return null;
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.catchError()` before `.then()` fixed it for me.

So initially I had this:

```dart
someAsyncFunction().then((value) {
  // Handle success
}).catchError((error) {
  // Handle error
  return ""; // Used to complain here.
});
```

But after I do this, it stops throwing the error.

```dart
someAsyncFunction().catchError((error) {
  // Handle error
  return ""; // Doesn't complain anymore!
}).then((value) {
  // Handle success
});
```

Note that I return an empty string since my function has the return value `Future<String?>`.

```dart
Future<String?> someAsyncFunction() {
  // logic
  return response;

  if (some_error) {
    throw Exception("Error!");
  }
}
```